# Selecting rows where all values not in another table

Tags: sql

This is my table design:

```
REQUEST(R_ID,attr1,attr2)
WIPS(R_ID,WIP,attr3,attr4)
SHIPPING(WIP,attr5,attr6)
```

How do I limit my query to show the information from `REQUEST` but only where the all of the `wips` associated between `REQUEST` and `WIPS` are not in the `SHIPPING` table.  For example, the `SHIPPING` table has all of the `WIPS` that have been shipped, I only want to show the `REQUEST` rows where all of the `WIPS` have not shipped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-Steve

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `not exists`:

```
select *
from request r
where not exists (select 1
                  from wips w join
                       shipping s
                       on w.wip = s.wip
                  where w.r_id = r.r_id
                 )
```

That is, if anything exists in the shipping table for the wips on the request, then filter out the row.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for rows where `wips associated between REQUEST and WIPS`
it is not enough to rule out a connection to `shipping`. We need to establish a connection to `wip` to start with:

```
SELECT *
FROM   request r
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   wips w1
   LEFT   JOIN shipping s USING (wip)
   WHERE  w1.r_id = r.r_id
   AND    s.wip IS NULL
  )
```

If your RDBMS does not have the USING clause for JOIN, use instead:

```
   LEFT   JOIN shipping s ON s.wip = w1.wip
```

**If** you actually mean, that none of the wips associated with a `request` can be connected to a `shipping`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   request r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   wips w1
   JOIN   shipping s USING (wip)
   WHERE  w1.r_id = r.r_id
  )
-- but has to have at least one wip connected?
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   wips w1
   WHERE  w1.r_id = r.r_id
  )
```

[-> **SQLfiddle** demonstrating important details.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9771c/1)